# Php Facebook Canvas SWF object embed

Tags: php, facebook, canvas, flash

Can anyone explain how to embed a swf object into a facebook canvas page via PHP.

```
<?php

function sswf($swf,$swfh,$swfw) { 
    echo "<OBJECT classid='clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000'  
    codebase='http://active.macromedia.com/flash2/cabs/swflash.cab#version=4,0,0,0' ID=objects WIDTH=$swfw HEIGHT=$swfh><PARAM  
    NAME=movie VALUE='$swf'><EMBED src='$swf' WIDTH=$swfw HEIGHT=$swfh TYPE='application/x-shockwave-flash'  
    PLUGINSPAGE='http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash'></OBJECT>";
}

$mf = "mmmm1.swf";
sswf($mf,690,1000);

?>
```

The code above no longer works although it did last week.... What's wrong with it?

Comment: what does mean "no longer works" ?

Comment: Maybe the "mmmm1.swf" is simply not where you think it is? Also, I recommend using [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to embed flash in your page.

Answer (score 1):

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>


   <script type="text/javascript">
   var params = {allowFullScreen:'false', allowscriptaccess:'always', wmode:'opaque'};
   var flashvars = {};
   var attributes = { name:"xxx", id:"xxx" };
   swfobject.embedSWF("xxx.swf?<? echo(time()) ?>", "xxx", "520", "500", "9.0", null, flashvars, params, attributes);
   </script>

   <div id="fb-root"></div>
   <div id="xxx">
   <h1>You need at least Flash Player 9 to view this page.</h1>
   <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="https://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a></p>
   </div>
```